# Create a transaction object in ethers with transaction Hash

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I was trying to find out if I could wait for the transaction to be mined from just transaction hash using node.js backend. I found this piece of code:

```js
const isTransactionMined = async(transactionHash) => {
    const txReceipt = await provider.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash);
    if (txReceipt && txReceipt.blockNumber) {
        return txReceipt;
    }
}
```

But the problem with is code is that it returns nothing if the transaction is pending. I don't have the access to the signer object. So, is there a way to wait for the transaction to be mined with only knowing the tx hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [provider.getTransaction](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/single-page/#/v5/concepts/)

> If a transaction has not been mined, this method will search the
> transaction pool. Various backends may have more restrictive
> transaction pool access (e.g. if the gas price is too low or the
> transaction was only recently sent and not yet indexed) in which case
> this method may also return null.

```
const txReceipt = await provider.getTransaction(transactionHash)
```